# Какие есть ограничения на аватарки?

Tags: обсуждение, правила, аватар-пользователя

Недавно я увидел аватарку одного пользователя (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/426807/l-proud-of-it) и я не уверен разрешены ли аватарки такого вида ([сама аватарка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crHv4.jpg?s=328&g=1)). В справке я ничего не нашёл, поэтому решил задать вопрос. Какие аватарки разрешены, а какие запрещены? Что будет с участником который поставит запрещённую аватарку?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7764/

Comment: А что в этой аватарке не так?

Comment: Тема не раскрыта...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если аватарка является неприемлемой, то она будет удалена, а пользователь предупреждён о том, что так делать не надо. Такие случаи уже были.

Что касается конкретной аватарки, я не считаю её недопустимой. Хотя, вполне может быть, что другие модераторы со мной не согласятся и она всё же будет удалена.

Comment: Такое даже Facebook бы не удалил.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а теперь надо равняться на Facebook?

Comment: @avp надо быть лучше их, поэтому и пример привёл.